# MySQL Performance Planning

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm in the process of writing a system to search through a MySQL database of real estate listings.  I'm concerned about performance and wanted some input on how to handle this.

The table that will be the most frequently queried is the 'listings' table and will contain over 600k records with 86 columns.  This table will also be updated every 30 minutes as listings change.

Almost every search will be against records with a status of 'active' which will be about 15k of the 600k records.  However, I need to retain all of the records for our internal reports.  Also, each query will likely be searching for various parameters (#beds, #baths, etc) so caching may not be feasible.

I was considering maintaining a second table containing the PK's of records marked 'active'.  Create a view of the tables joined on the listing's PK.  However, I know that under certain conditions, Views can be very inefficient.

I did have the thought of maintaining two databases since the inactive listings won't be searched frequently and will require less maintenance.

Fortunately it's not in production yet and I have time for performance testing.  One more thing, this will be hosted on a dedicated Linux server with the front-end written in PHP.  Any insight offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **86** columns? Really? I think you need to re-think your design.

Comment: I wouldn't create a separate table.  MySQL shouldn't have a problem searching 600K records using status as it's criteria.  You could index the status field to improve performance and frequently searched fields.

Comment: "maintaining a second table containing the PK's of records marked 'active'" <-- Are you planning to hand-code an index? Because just using an index on that column instead is going to be easier and faster. Also, are most of your columns tiny or numbers (like the mentioned number of beds)?

Comment: njk - the listings are pulled from an external data source maintained for all of the real estate companies in the region.  Thus, this part of it isn't my design.  Carsten - Most of the data is relatively small with a few text columns. Tom - This may be my only option.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you create an archive table.  You could set up a process to run every 30 minutes or once per day, depending on the requirements.

The archive table would have the same columns as the original table plus and EffDate and EndDate, that have the dates/date times when the record is active.

Such a table will make it possible to recreate the history at any point in time -- something that will prove useful, I'm sure.

You will need code to create this.  The basic logic is to lookup each record in your table with the most current version in the archive (`EndDate is null` and `id = id`).  Then:

1. If new record is not present, create a new record with the current date as `EffDate`.
2. If present and all columns are the same, do nothing.
3. Otherwise update `EndDate` on the archive record and do (1).
4. Any archive records that do not have a new record at all should have `EndDate` set to the current date.

Typically, I have such tables updated once per day.

In code that does this, I have a big ugly query (Excel helps me build it) that does the comparisons and determines which records are "New", "Modified", and "Removed".  The "Removed" and "Modified" records have the current `EndDates` set to the current date.  The "New" and "Modified" records then get a new record with the `EffDate` set to the current date.

The values for `EndDate` and `EffDate` might be one more or less than stated, depending on how the updates really work.  For a nightly update, for instance, the `EffDate` might be set to tomorrow or even to the date when the listing takes effect.

Comment: I thought of this too, however it wouldn't work as the listings move on/off market frequently.  A home may be on the market (active status) for a few months, then the sellers take it off market (expired) for whatever reason.  Legally, I can only publicly display those that are active.

Comment: @Raythe . . . That would still work.  The archive table would not be on public display.  It would be a method for reconstructing history.

Comment: So basically when status changes to active, insert that into my active listings table and delete the record from the archive.  Then do the reverse when it's changes to a non-active state.  Is this correct?